# Why doesn't my solution to Euler #7 (10001st prime) work?

Tags: ruby

This is my code. The code doesn't run at all which leads me to believe that the problem is an infinite loop or something of that sort.

```
# Question_7, Answer = 104743
# By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
# What is the 10 001st prime number?
def prime_at(x)
    primes = [2, 3]
    n = 4
    test = true
    while primes.length <= x
        primes.each do |i|
            if n % i != 0
                test = false
            end
        end
        if test == true
            primes.push(n)
        end
        n += 1
    end
    puts primes[-1]
end
prime_at(10001)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have an infinite loop. The bug is that once the variable `test` is set to `false` it never changes to `true`, so you are not adding elements into the primes array. That means that the condition of your loop `primes.length <= x` is going to be always true. Hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is wrong. `n%i != 0` means the number is not divisble by `i`, meaning the prime test should not fail. There's a lot of 'extra' syntax in here that makes your method a bit hard to understand. For example, `test == true` is redundant (if `test` is `true` or `false` or anything else, you can just say `if test`). `n%i != 0` returns a boolean value already, so that whole if statement around it is unneeded.

It may seem a bit odd to drop so many constructs found in other languages, but Ruby lets you express your ideas very clearly and understandably. Here's what I would suggest for this method (I didn't change your algorithm at all, this is simply a rewrite):

```
def prime_at(x)
  primes = [2,3]
  n = 4
  until primes.length == x
    primes << n if primes.all? {|p| n % p > 0 }
    n += 1
  end
  primes.last
end
```

Comment: prime_at(1) -> infinite loop